# Whenever I press windows key on keyboard it shows all open windows and gets stuck can't get out of the situation

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I use Ubuntu on a daily basis. As a animator I was working on a personal project on a open-source 3d program `Blender` all off a sudden it was looking like I pressed activities on top left corner but I was unable to get out of that mode. When this incident happened first I was not aware of the keyboard key which was causing this issue. Then again after few days this issue again appeared I almost forgot about it. Everytime I had to logout and login to fix the issue. Recently I discovered that the key which causing the issue was Windows key (the key with windows logo on keyboard). I don't see anyone complaining about this issue on the whole internet (maybe not I was unable to figure out what I have to search to solution for this issue).

For more information I recently updated my system to Ubuntu 21.04 form 20.10. Also, when this happens it's not like windows are not responding I can move mouse and do everything other than just quitting from that mode. Note keyboard doesn't seem to work while I was facing this issue. **`Please Help`**

Comment: I confirm this behavior: must be a bug. On Xorg, you can reset the shell with Alt+F2, r then <enter>. I also have an upgraded system. Perhaps, systems that are freshly installed do not have the issue.

Comment: Also, I have to mention not everytime this happens. For example I tried to try your fix and pressed windows key and it is not stuck. Meanwhile when i'm not pressing windows key intentionally it happens. Btw, thanks for your help.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if it happens on Xorg  or Wayland specifically.

Comment: It is indeed only occasionally. My "fix" is not a fix, it is just a way to continue your session if you are on Xorg. Of course, you could determine whether you have it on Wayland. I was running Xorg. I actually moved to Gnome 40 on my system, so I cannot do any testing.